# How to get the type hints of native PHP class constructors

Tags: php, oop, reflection

When using the `ReflectionParameter` class to loop through native PHP class `__construct()`  parameters, I've noticed that the type-hints of the parameters in the docs aren't matching up to what I'm getting using the class methods.

For example the `DateTime` object:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('DateTime');
$constructor = $reflector->getConstructor();

if ($constructorParams = $constructor->getParameters()) {
    foreach ($constructorParams as $i => $param) {
        var_dump($param->getClass());
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
null
null
```

But [according to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) the class description is:

```
public DateTime::__construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )
```

Shouldn't the `$timezone` parameter have a type-hint of `DateTimeZone`? Or is the parameter not actually type-hinted, and rather the docs are just telling you what should be passed in?

Also, when outputting the names they are different as well: `var_dump($param->name)` outputs:

```
time
object
```

However if I were to do a reflection on `PDO`, a var dump of the names outputs correctly like in the docs:

```
dsn
username
passwd
options
```

Comment: Yes, I'd say the parameter isn't type-hinted and the docs are just telling you what should be passed in. I suppose the type checking is just done internally. Given you can do things like `new DateTime(null)` and `new DateTime(2018)` without any errors or warnings, that seems to be the case.

Comment: That makes sense. I wish the parameter names matched up to the variables in the docs though, `$time` does, but `$timezone` shows up as `object`. The PDO object shows up accurately though. Checking something like `ArrayObject` shows up almost 100% accurate too with the exception of `$flags` actually being `ar_flags`

Comment: According to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php), it sounds like PHP considers this to be a bug.

Comment: Good info! Thanks.

Comment: `DateTime::__construct`'s parameters are defined [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.4/ext/date/php_date.c#L163) whereas `PDO::__construct` can be found [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.4/ext/pdo/pdo_dbh.c#L1202). You'll see that parameter names in source code just don't match with the ones in documentation.

Comment: bug fixed https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76131 (mismatch arginfo for date_create).

Answer (score 0):

I has been [fixed](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76131) try using the same or follow the below code,

```
 $reflector = new ReflectionClass('DateTime');
    $constructor = $reflector->getConstructor();

    if ($constructorParams = $constructor->getParameters()) {
        foreach ($constructorParams as $i => $param) {
            $name = $param->getClass() ? $param->getClass()->name : $param->name;

            var_dump($name);
        }
    }

    $reflector = new ReflectionClass('ArrayObject');
    $constructor = $reflector->getConstructor();

    if ($constructorParams = $constructor->getParameters()) {
        foreach ($constructorParams as $i => $param) {
            $name = $param->getClass() ? $param->getClass()->name : $param->name;

            var_dump($name);
        }
    }
```

for more details you can refer [Fix](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76131), [dateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) and [arrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.construct.php)